# Python freezes when accessing string value in subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess, ctypes

I spent nearly the whole day with this and came to the end of my knowledge:

I want to change a shared multiprocessing.Value string in the subprocess, but python hangs as soon as the subprocess is trying to change the shared value.

Below an example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, freeze_support
from ctypes import c_wchar_p

def test(x):
    with x.get_lock():
        x.value = 'THE TEST WORKED'
    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    freeze_support()
    value = Value(c_wchar_p, '')
    p = Process(target=test, args = (value,))
    p.start()
    print(p.pid)
    # this try block is to also allow p.run() 
    try:
            p.join()
            p.terminate()
    except:
            pass
    print(value.value)
```

What I tried and does not work:

- I tried ctypes `c_wchar_p` and `c_char_p`, but both result in the same freezing.
- I tried also without `x.get_lock()`
- I tried also without `freeze_support()`

What works (but does not help):

- Using a float as the shared value (`value = Value('d',0)` and `x.value = 1`).
- Running the Process without starting a subprocess (replace `p.start()` with `p.run()` )

I am using Windows 10 64 bit and Python 3.6.4 (Spyder, but also tried outside of Spyder).

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared pointer won't work in another process because the pointer is only valid in the process in which it was created.  Instead, use an array:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def test(x):
    x.value = b'Test worked!'

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    x = mp.Array('c',15)
    p = mp.Process(target=test, args = (x,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(x.value)
```

Output:

```
b'Test worked!'
```

Note that array type `'c'` is specialized and returns a `SynchronizedString` vs. other types that return `SynchronizedArray`.  Here's how to use type `'u'` for example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from ctypes import *

def test(x):
    x.get_obj().value = 'Test worked!'

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    x = mp.Array('u',15)
    p = mp.Process(target=test, args = (x,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(x.get_obj().value)
```

Output:

```
Test worked!
```

Note that operations on the wrapped value that are non-atomic such as `+=` that do read/modify/write should be protected with a `with x.get_lock():` context manager.

Comment: Oh I did not see from https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types that this is a pointer and not a simple string variable. Thanks!
However, what I do not understand is, why your code is not working when using 'u' as ctype. Then when trying to access x.value, I get "SynchronizedArray has no attribute 'value' "

Comment: @M.Beining The type returned by `mp.Array('c',15)` is `SynchronizedString`, but `mp.Array('u',15)` returns `SynchronizedArray`.  I found a note in [multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Array): "Note that an array of ctypes.c_char has value and raw attributes which allow one to use it to store and retrieve strings.", so 'c' is specialized.  I'll update my answer illustrating both.